# Update panel in master page stops JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, webmethod

Actual issue is I have three anchors which is for time in and time out and for menu  when page load first time all works fine but when I click on time in or time out button then menu button stops working . with out update panel all thing works fine but only time in and out button load page on click only I place update panel only for time in and out to avoid page load

1-menu button shows menu item on click 
2-Time in and out  buttons mark attendance respectively

```
 Protected Sub Anchortimein_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Anchortimein.ServerClick
```

Some code here

```
    End Sub


 Protected Sub AnchortimeOut_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AnchortimeOut.ServerClick
```

Some code here
        End Sub

```
Public Sub AttendanceValidationMessage(strmsg As String, msg As String)
        Dim strMessage As String = strmsg
        Dim strScript As String = "alert('" & strMessage & " " & msg & "'); "
        If (Not Me.Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript")) Then
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "clientScript", strScript, True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

```js
// Open/hide menu
  $('#open-menu').on('touchend click', function(event)
  {
   event.preventDefault();

   // Check if valid touch-click event
   if (!$.template.processTouchClick(this, event))
   {
    return;
   }

   // Close shortcuts
   bod.removeClass('shortcuts-open');

   // If in wide screen mode, show/hide side menu, else open/close drop-down menu
   bod.toggleClass($.template.mediaQuery.is('desktop') || $.template.mediaQuery.is('tablet-landscape') ? 'menu-hidden' : 'menu-open');

   // Refresh drop-down menu size if needed
   watchMenuSize();
  });

  // Close drop-down menu
  bod.on('click', function(event)
  {
   // Check if open, and if the click is not on the menu or on the open button
   if (bod.hasClass('menu-open') && !$(event.target).closest('#open-menu, #menu').length)
   {
    bod.removeClass('menu-open');
   }
  });
```

```css
Css for ul li 
ul.topmainmenu {

position: relative;
width: 99.4%;
height: 38px;
z-index: 9;
margin: 4.5px 0;

}

ul.topmainmenu > li {
float: right;
list-style: none;
}
CSS for Menu 
#open-menu {
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px 8px 11px;
 }
 #title-bar + #open-menu {
  top: 35px;
 }
 body.reversed #open-menu {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
 }
 #open-menu > span {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../img/standard/sprites.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  }
  body.reversed #open-menu > span {
   background-position: 0 -17px;
  }
  #open-menu:hover > span {
   background-position: -20px 0;
   }
   body.reversed #open-menu:hover > span {
    background-position: -20px -17px;
   }
  body.menu-hidden #open-menu > span {
   background-position: 0 -17px;
   }
   body.menu-hidden.reversed #open-menu > span {
    background-position: 0 0;
   }
   body.menu-hidden #open-menu:hover > span {
    background-position: -20px -17px;
    }
    body.menu-hidden.reversed #open-menu:hover > span {
     background-position: -20px 0;
    }

 /* Menu opener icon */
 #open-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 5px;
  right: 8px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  body.reversed #open-menu {
   left: 8px;
   right: auto;
  }
  .fixed-title-bar > #open-menu {
   position: fixed;
  }
  #open-menu > span {
   padding: 0 8px 0 30px;
   background: url(../img/menu.png) no-repeat 7px center;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 27px;
   line-height: 27px;
  }

  #open-menu > span,
  #open-shortcuts {
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #020203;
   color: white;
   -webkit-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   -moz-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   background-color: #454545;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
  }

CSS for InOut 
.open-menu23 {
  z-index: 4;
  top: 65px;
  right: 43.3%;
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  
  }
  body.reversed .open-menu23 {
   left: 8px;
   right: auto;
  }
  .fixed-title-bar > .open-menu23 {
   position: static;
  }
  .open-menu23 > span {
   padding: 0 8px 0 30px;
   background: url(../img/inout5.png) no-repeat 7px center;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 27px;
   line-height: 27px;
  }

  .open-menu23 > span {
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #020203;
   color: white;
   -webkit-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   -moz-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   background-color: #454545;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width:56px;
   
  }
 .open-menu24 {
  z-index: 6;
  top: 65px;
  right: 50.8%;
     
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }
  body.reversed .open-menu24 {
   left: 8px;
   right: auto;
  }
  .fixed-title-bar > .open-menu24 {
   /*position: fixed;*/
   position: static  !important;
  }
  .open-menu24 > span {
   padding: 0 8px 0 30px;
   background: url(../img/inout4.png) no-repeat 7px center;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 27px;
   line-height: 27px;
  }

  .open-menu24 > span {
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #020203;
   color: white;
   -webkit-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   -moz-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
   background-color: #454545;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   width:55px;
   
  }
```

```html
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
 <header role="banner" id="title-bar" style="padding:0px;">    
  <h2></h2>
        <ul class="topmainmenu">
           <li style="margin: 0px -1.2px;"><a href="#" id="open-menu" ><span>Menu</span></a> </li>
           <%If AccountPagePermissionBLL.IsPageHasPermissionOf(15, 1) Then%>
            <li style="margin: 0px -1.2px;"><a href="../AccountAdmin/AdminMain.aspx" id="open-menu4"><span><asp:Label ID="lbladmin" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="Admin Options" ></asp:Label></span></a>  </li>
        <%End If%>
    
            <%If Session("Role") = "Administrator" Then%>
            <li style="margin: 0px -1.0px;"><a href="../Employee/EmployeeProfile.aspx" id="open-menu22"><span><asp:Label ID="nametop" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="<%$ Resources:TimeLive.Web, LoggedIn As:%>" ></asp:Label></span></a>    </li>
        <%Else %>
        <%If AccountPagePermissionBLL.IsPageHasPermissionOf(15, 1) Then%>
            <li style="margin: 0px -1.0px;"><a style="right:210px;" href="../Employee/EmployeeProfile.aspx" id="open-menu2"><span><asp:Label ID="nametop2" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="<%$ Resources:TimeLive.Web, LoggedIn As:%>" ></asp:Label></span></a>    </li>
            <%Else%>
            <li style="margin: 0px -1.0px;"><a style="right:90px;" href="../Employee/EmployeeProfile.aspx" id="open-menu21"><span><asp:Label ID="nametop3" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="<%$ Resources:TimeLive.Web, LoggedIn As:%>" ></asp:Label></span></a>    </li>
        <%End If%>    
        <%End If%>
       
         <li style="margin: 0px -1.2px;"><a href="#" runat="server" id="AnchortimeOut" class="open-menu23"><span><asp:label ID="lblTimeOut"  runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="<%$ Resources:TimeLive.Web, Time Out%>" ></asp:label></span></a></li>
         <li style="margin: 0px -1.2px;"><a href="../Employee/Default.aspx" runat="server" id="Anchortimein" class="open-menu24"><span><asp:label ID="lblTimeIn"   runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text="<%$ Resources:TimeLive.Web, Time In%>" ></asp:label></span></a></li>
        
        
         </ul>
  </header>
       </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: bod is for body in jquery old versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve by Putting update panels inside the li

Answer (score 0):

Write all code function `RebindmyStuff`  and work is fine because `updatepanel` not load the jQuery after any method click

---

```
function pageLoad()

 {

 RebindmyStuff();

 }

function RebindmyStuff()

{

  $(document).ready(function() 
 {

   // Open/hide menu

    $('#open-menu').on('touchend click', function(event)

    {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Check if valid touch-click event
        if (!$.template.processTouchClick(this, event))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Close shortcuts
        bod.removeClass('shortcuts-open');

        // If in wide screen mode, show/hide side menu, else open/close drop-down menu
        bod.toggleClass($.template.mediaQuery.is('desktop') || $.template.mediaQuery.is('tablet-landscape') ? 'menu-hidden' : 'menu-open');

        // Refresh drop-down menu size if needed
        watchMenuSize();
    });

    // Close drop-down menu
    bod.on('click', function(event)
    {
        // Check if open, and if the click is not on the menu or on the open button
        if (bod.hasClass('menu-open') && !$(event.target).closest('#open-menu, #menu').length)
        {
            bod.removeClass('menu-open');
        }
        });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event delegation instead of binding:

```
$(document).on('touchend click', '#open-menu', function(event) { ... });
```